# Storing Passwords for websites on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, password-management

I'm looking for a way to store passwords on my Ubuntu 
I've been using RoboForm on windows, and saw that it should be 
Safer than letting FireFox auto-complete my passwords because 
It's better encrypted, I'm willing to do so on my Ubuntu as well 
(Don't really care about using RoboForm specifically) 
I heard that there's a program called Gnome Keyring but I saw that the browser 
Integration is somewhat lacking, any suggestions?

Comment: "it's better encrypted" depends solely on what master password you choose. Firefox, KeePass, RoboForm - no matter which you use, having a short dictionary password will make all encryption moot if someone gets hold of the database.

Answer (score 2):

Check out KeePass, it works on Windows and Linux (and Mac and a lot of mobile devices). It has a feature where it stays minimized and allows you to auto complete forms with it. You just open it, type in your master password or keyfile, it decrypts, and it is ready to go. If you close it, then passwords can no longer be auto filled in which is nice.

http://keepass.info/

Comment: Late by a minute.

Comment: I was late by a minute? Seems odd that if you sort by oldest, my post shows up on top. I posted at 2010-06-27 16:20:59Z, and David posted at 2010-06-27 16:22:19Z

Answer (score 1):

I use [keepass](http://keepass.info/) to store all my passwords including those for websites, which works fine under Wine (for the older 1.x line that I currently still use) or more directly if you have Mono installed (which Ubuntu does by default IIRC) and use the 2.x line.

It doesn't integrate completely with the browser (you need to initiate the entering of the password rather than is being do automatically) but I consider this to be a GoodThing(tm).

There are several other similar tool out there too, if you find reason to not like keepass.

Comment: Actually, just use AutoType. Still not *quite* as fast, but pretty close.

Comment: is that keepassx?

Comment: Keepass has a fork for a native linux version named KeepassX : http://www.keepassx.org/

No need to use Wine, plus it has auto type.

Comment: FYI, both 1.x and 2.x lines are still in active development and have almost the same feature sets.

Answer (score 0):

Other people have mentioned KeePass; I use [KeePassX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/keepassx/) which is a cross-platform port of KeePass. It uses the Qt GUI toolkit instead of .NET/Mono. I can tell you from personal experience that it's excellent software.